# Regex find a specific character zero or one or multiple time in a string

Tags: regex

I'm upgrading a Symfony app with VSCode and I have numerous occurences of this kind of string :

```
@Template("Area:Local:delete.html.twig")
```

or

```
@Template("Group:add.html.twig")
```

In this case, I want to replace all the `:` with `/` to have :

```
@Template("Area/Local/delete.html.twig")
```

I can't think of doing it manually, so I was looking for a regular expression for a search/replace in the editor.

I've been toying with this fearsome beast without luck (i'm really dumb in regexp) :
`@Template\("([:]*)"`
`@Template\("(.*?)"`
`@Template\("[a-zA-Z.-]{0,}[:]")`

Still, I think there should be a "simple" regexp for this kind of standard replacement.

Anyone has any clue ? Thank you for any hint

Comment: You say you do this in VSCode, but where exactly? In the file search and replace feature (on the left, the magnifying glass)? Or a single document?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew there is a regex toggle in both search controls, the one with a dot and a star

Comment: @RichardMuvirimi But they use totally different regex engines. UI control appearance have nothing to do here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew they simply need to do a simple search and replace but using regex, doesn't matter what engine is used. Python has a different engine from php but that does not stop one from using regexes

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Since there are a lot of files to process (that's why i'm looking for the power of regex), it's in the search and replace feature (CTRL +Shift +F) I'm looking in. For a single document (a controller), even big, i would even look manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex with a capture group: `(@Template.*):`.

And replace with this `$1/`.

[image]

But you'll have to use replace all until there's no `:` left, that won't take long.

Just explaining a lit bit more, everything between the parenthesis is a capture group that we can reference later in replace field, if we had `(tem)(pla)te`, `$1` would be `tem` and `$2` would be `pla`

Comment: Several search replace, but as you say : it's quick.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Regex!

You can use this regex `@Template\("(.[^\(\:]*)?(?:\:)(.[^\(\:]*)?(?:\:)?(.[^\(\:]*)?"\)` and replacement would simply be `@Template\("$1/$2/$3`

You can test it out at https://regex101.com/r/VfZHFa/2

Explanation: The linked site will give a better explanation than I can write here, and has test cases you can use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works on regex101 site, but in VSCode, I have the pattern error : `invalid regular expression, invalid escape`

Comment: Didn't think I had to spell it out you could have used the code generator and saved it to a file and then executed it in the terminal, nevertheless just needed to remove the escape character "\" before the colon ":" so that it would be @Template\("(.[^\(:]*)?(?::)(.[^\(:]*)?(?::)?(.[^\(:]*)?"\)

Comment: Although i clicked on the copy to clipboard button on the site, it didn't remove the escape character. Sorry for the display of lack of knowledge in regex from me. With this pattern, this also solve the problem. Thank you anyways

Comment: @Overdose ok, kindly asking for a vote if this also helped solve your problem